# how to add a class to one dynamic menu item?

Tags: php, javascript, css, dynamic, menuitem

php:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, menuname
        FROM table
        WHERE status = 'active'
        ORDER BY order ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$menu = "<ul>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $menu.= "<li><a href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['menuname']}</a></li>";
}
$menu.= "</ul>\n";
```

html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?id=1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="?id=2">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="?id=3">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="?id=4">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="?id=5">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'd like to add the class="lhidden" to the "News" (not the 2nd menu,because the order can be changed).

```
<li class="lhidden"><a href="?id=2">News</a></li>
```

How can i do that? I'm just learning javascript and php,so I have no idea :S

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $menu.= "<li><a".($row['menuname']=='News'?' class="lhidden"':'')." href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['menuname']}</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: You mean

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$menu.= "<li".($row['menuname']=='News'?'class="lhidden"':'').">
<a href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['menuname']}</a></li>";
}

That's a great idea,thank you :)

Comment: @darksoul90 what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is pretty easy:

```
$('a[href="?id=2"]').parent().addClass('lhidden');
```

This would first find the specific anchor, then add your class to its parent.

Documentation for the selector part here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sql = "SELECT id, menuname
   FROM table
   WHERE status = 'active'
   ORDER BY order ASC";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $menu = "<ul>\n";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   if($row['id']==2)
   {  
       $menu.= "<li class=\"lhidden\"><a href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['menuname']}</a></li>";
   }
   else
   {
       $menu.= "<li><a href=\"?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['menuname']}</a></li>";
   }
   $menu.= "</ul>\n";
```